# Delete line containing a particular word as well as the previous line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to get the code that deletes every line containing the string `/movie/` and the previous line (the `/` character is included in `/movie/`).

Example :

Before Code :

```
#EXTINF:-1,Wreck-It Ralph
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/movie/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/104880.mp4
#EXTINF:-1,Wrinkle-Free
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/movie/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/105060.mp4
#EXTINF:-1,DR | TELEMICRO 5
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/99633
#EXTINF:-1,Wrong Mistake - Short Movie
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/movie/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/106840.mp4
#EXTINF:-1,DR | TELESISTEMA 11
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/99632
#EXTINF:-1,Wreck-It
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/movie/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/104707.mp4
#EXTINF:-1,DR | TELEUNIVERSO
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/99631
```

After Code :

```
#EXTINF:-1,DR | TELEMICRO 5
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/99633
#EXTINF:-1,DR | TELESISTEMA 11
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/99632
#EXTINF:-1,DR | TELEUNIVERSO
http://p5.giffy.be:8080/RghyHCIE4i/SDrQatrZkx/99631
```

Comment: @ggorlen please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^.*?\r\n.*?\/movie\/.*?(\r\n|$)
```

Step-by-step:

1. Open Find and Replace with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to focus on Find what.
3. Enter the above regex.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to enable regular expression mode. Ensure ". matches newline" is off.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to Replace All.

How it works:

```
^  # anchor to beginning of line 
 .*?  # lazily match zero or more characters
    \r\n  # match carriage return and line feed
        .*?  # lazily match zero or more characters
           \/movie\/  # match literal /movie/
                    .*?  # lazily match zero or more characters
                       (\r\n|$)  # match carriage return and line feed or EOL
```

Comment: Thank you , your code works good but it miss a little thing :
for example if the last line of my text contains /movie/ , it deletes everything which good but it keeps the last line as it is , can  you fix  it please

Comment: That's because the last line doesn't end with `\r\n`. Use alternation: `(\r\n|$)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to match the first line and match a unicode newline sequence `\R`. Then match the second line with `/movie/` and at the end match `\R`

**Find what:**

```
^.*\R.*/movie/.*\R
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except newline
- `\R` Match unicode newline sequence
- `.*/movie/.*` Match `/movie/` in the string
- `\R` Match unicode newline sequence

**Replace with:**

Leave empty

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z1dsvo/1)